# Why is flutter throwing an Bad UTF-8 encoding error when I get json data?

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, utf-8

```
  class _CalendarScreenState extends State<CalendarScreen> {
      Future<void> calendarCheck() async {
        http.Response response = await http
            .get(Uri.parse('https://192.168.0.250/BackEnd/calendar.php'));
        var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    
        final Iterable list = body['items'];
        for (var items in list) {
          var title = (items['summary']);
          var desc = (items['description']);
          var start = (items['start']);
          var finish = (items['end']);
    
 
          print(desc);
 
        }
      }


     "description": "Mixed Genre (Cheer/Dance/Gymnastics)\n\n�Dec 24th, Dec 29th & Jan 4th � \nSession 1: 9:30 – 12:00� \nSession 2: 12:30 – 3:00 \n$10 per session\n\nAttend 1 or 2 sessions per day \nIf you attend all day BYO lunch\n\nBookings essential"
```

Everything is working fine on my data pull from the calendar I am getting the events from, but when I try to get the description it throws the
Finished with error: Bad UTF-8 encoding (U+FFFD; REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) found while decoding string:

I have looked at the other suggestions and I am not seeing if I need to sanitise the characters or something else?

this is a portion of the json code returned by the google calendar I need to grab information from.

`{ "kind": "calendar#events", "etag": "\"p32k97kk0vfpfe0g\"", "summary": "insanitytreme@gmail.com", "updated": "2022-05-22T11:04:30.745Z", "timeZone": "Australia/Adelaide", "accessRole": "reader", "defaultReminders": [], "nextPageToken": "CigKGjUwbDRwNmNrZ3NxdmdhMWgycHRjNmo3cjhvGAEggICA48rCrLkXGg8IABIAGKiT0oD78vcCIAEiBwgCELXe2SU=", "items": [ { "kind": "calendar#event", "etag": "\"2896706282246000\"", "id": "36mlmanph90539q8dpmg3uomok", "status": "confirmed", "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MzZtbG1hbnBoOTA1MzlxOGRwbWczdW9tb2sgaW5zYW5pdHljaGVlcmV4dHJlbWVAbQ", "created": "2015-11-24T08:19:01.000Z", "updated": "2015-11-24T08:19:01.123Z", "summary": "Playford Pageant", "description": "(ICE manager and Head Tumbling Coach)", "location": "Queen Street, Queen St, Smithfield SA 5114, Australia", "creator": { "email": "insanitytreme@gmail.com", "displayName": "Insanity", "self": true }, "organizer": { "email": "insanitytreme@gmail.com", "displayName": "Insanity Cheer Extreme", "self": true }, "start": { "dateTime": "2015-11-28T08:45:00+10:30", "timeZone": "UTC" }, "end": { "dateTime": "2015-11-28T10:45:00+10:30", "timeZone": "UTC" }, "iCalUID": "36mlmanph90539q8dpmg3uomok@google.com", "sequence": 0, "eventType": "default" },`

this is the php call

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'.$calName.'/events?key='.$key.'');

$data = json_decode($json); 
    if($data != null){ 
        echo $json;
    } 
  else{
        echo json_encode("Error");
 }
```

Comment: What is the original string?  Are you sure that the original string is UTF-8?

Comment: The original example you showed shows Unicode replacement characters (�), presumably from a malformed string.  The new string you've posted does not indicate that at all and has a completely different contents.  Please try to figure out the source of the � characters.

Comment: I have a feed here [link](http://insanityallstars.com.au/BackEnd/calendar.php)

Comment: I tried your code with that link and cannot reproduce your problem.  Can you please provide a reproducible example and a stacktrace?